# Animating quad using vertex shader

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, vertex-shader

I have a grassland where i have rendered a quad using instanced rendering with a texture containing alpha channel.

So far it looks ideal, except it doesn't move/animate. its just a quad rendered onto the screen, which just sits still and does nothing.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve here is simple, I want a way to be able to move the quad, using some trignometric function [sine] for example, but I dont want to move the whole quad, only the upper part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[shearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) is what you are after.

first transform the quad so the bottom is at Y=0 then multiply with

```
[1,d,0,0,
 0,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,0,
 0,0,0,1]
```

and then transform it to where you need it to be

and let d vary around 0

Comment: That worked like a charm :P
can i give more votes to the answer? :D :D